# Dynamically add filter to Linq queryable which calls a DataContext method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression, iqueryable

I am having some trouble creating an expression to add to a queryable as a filter condition.  I would like to replicate something the following:

Starting with a simple queryable:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = from customer in context.Customer
    select customer;
```

I would like to dynamically add a filter condition that involves calling a method on the DataContext:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = from customer in context.Customer
    where customer.Name == context.ConvertValueForSearch(searchString)
    select customer;
```

so that the 'ConvertValueForSearch' calls the appropriate database function when it is evaluated.

The above produces the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[CustName]
   FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t0]
   WHERE [t0].[CustName] = [dbo].[fnConvertSearchStringValue](@p0)',N'@p0 varchar(8000)',@p0='Foo'
```

We have a number of DataContext derived types, so the ConvertValueForSearch is defined through an interface (ISearchValueConverter) which each of our DataContext types implement.

I am not sure how to correctly create the expression to call the ConvertValueForSearch(string searchValue) on the DataContext and then create the final  Expression.Equal made up of the property accessor for the Customer.Name and the method call to ConvertValueForSearch so that the filter can be applied to the queryable with a CreateQuery.

If I start with something like the following:

```
... code executed in the repository instance
<Func<Manager<TEntity, TRootDal, TUniqueIdentifierType>, string, string>> convertSearchStringValueLambda =
    (manager, searchValueToConvert) => manager.DataContextForConversionForSpecificContext.ConvertValueForSearch(searchValueToConvert);
var invokedCall = Expression.Invoke(convertSearchStringValueLambda, Expression.Constant(this), Expression.Constant(searchValue));

...code executed in the filter item instance to apply the filter to the queryable
// the accessor for Customer.Name    
LambdaExpression propertyAccessor = Entity<TDalEntity>.GetPropertyAccessorExpression<string>(this.FilterField);
BinaryExpression filterExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyAccessor.Body, filterValue);

Expression filter = Expression.Lambda(filterExpression, propertyAccessor.Parameters);

query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<TDalEntity>(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { query.ElementType },
        query.Expression,
        filter));
```

the call to fnConvertSearchStringValue is done in a separate call to the db and the results of it are passed to the database when the queryable is used.  Although that might be OK in some circumstances, I really need the function to be called as in the SQL that was generated with that Linq-to-SQL above.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: turns out that the way the DataContext was being accessed got in the way of the remote / local determination.  Using a different property that drilled through our context wrapper to the db context in a different manner allowed linq to push this down to the database where it was resolved successfully...